# Setting layout extents using expressions in qgis layout editor

Tags: qgis, layouts

Is there a way to set my extents using a specific feature's bounds in my qgis layout? I thought of using expressions in the "Extents" box, but i am not sure whether it is possible to refer to a feature's bounds directly via the expression editor in the layout. If there is a way would someone please indicate how?

From the layout editor window:

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried the following expression but don't know what to do from there:

`get_feature('Segments_f03a4f8c_62f6_4377_b8fb_d6f60a9016ce', "Segment", 2)`

What does `get_feature` return? How can I extract the geometry from that? Can I then use the `bounds` method to get min and max bound values from the extracted feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you can use something like:

```
 x(point_n(bounds(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Boundary-line-ceremonial-counties_region', 1))),1))
 y(point_n(bounds(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Boundary-line-ceremonial-counties_region', 1))),1))
```

to get the min-x/y of the bounds of the first feature in the layer ('Boundary-line-ceremonial_counties_region).

```
 x(point_n(bounds(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Boundary-line-ceremonial-counties_region', 1))),3))
 y(point_n(bounds(geometry(get_feature_by_id('Boundary-line-ceremonial-counties_region', 1))),3))
```

to get the max x/y.

PS. `get_feature` returns Returns the first feature of a layer matching a given attribute value. While `get_feature_by_id` returns the feature with an id on a layer.

Comment: But I suspect that you really want to use an atlas to step through each feature in turn

Comment: I tried using an atlas, but I have a background raster with "Current Canvas" min/max settings which means that the colors/legend change based on zoom level. This doesn't seem to be handled well by the Atlas generator....

Comment: Nevermind, the atlas option works well for what I need. I'll accept this answer although I haven't tested it...

Comment: would you also take a look at the related question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362272/page-legend-in-qgis-atlas-not-updating-properly-for-raster-layer-with-updated-c if you have a moment? Thankyou

Comment: Wouldn't it be more concise to use `x_min()`, `x_max()` etc.

Comment: probably, I wasn't sure where I was going when I started and ended up where I was :-)